# Enum & Fwrite Dilemma

Tags: c, delphi, delphi-2010

I was writing a program from C to Delphi so as to make its x64 version when I faced problems with **enum** & **fwrite**.

```
enum{ ou2bufsize=1<<16 };
byte ou2buf[ou2bufsize];
```

And,

```
fwrite( ou2buf, 1,l, h );
```

Can ya please tell me what these are & how are they declared in Delphi???

Comment: Why not read the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum{ ou2bufsize=1<<16 };` is a constant named `ou2bufsize` with a value of 65536 (1 shifted to the left by 16 bits).  The Delphi equivalent is:

```
const
  ou2bufsize = 1 shl 16;
```

`byte ou2buf[ou2bufsize];` is a fixed-sized array of bytes named `ou2buf` containing `ou2bufsize` number of array elements.  The Delphi equivalent is:

```
ou2buf: array[0..ou2bufsize-1] of byte;
```

`fwrite( ou2buf, 1,l, h );` is writing `l` number of 1-byte-size items from the starting memory address of `ou2buf` to the file represented by `h`.  The Delphi equivalent is:

```
FileWrite(h, ou2buf[0], l);
```

Where `h` is a `THandle` returned by `FileCreate()` or `FileOpen()` and `l` is the number of bytes to write.

Answer (score 1):

`enum{ ou2bufsize=1<<16 };` defines a constant called `ou2bufsize` having the value `1 shl 16` (1 shifted to the left by 16 bits).

`byte ou2buf[ou2bufsize];` defines an array (called `ou2buf`) of `ou2bufsize` bytes, numbered from `0` to `ou2bufsize-1`.

`fwrite( ou2buf, 1,l, h );` writes the first `l` bytes from `ou2buf` to the output handle `h`.